# IOT Precision farming/agriculture

Tags: light, nutrients, food-crops

Note I have asked also this in Earth science using agriculture Tag and here also because those are the agriculture communities as to my knowledge in stack exchange

Before asking my agriculture/farming related question I would like to give some context being form an engineering background .

Today IOT and Embedded firmware/hardware modules revolutionized innovation in many sectors including Agriculture in what is called Precision agriculture where every input attribute to the plant environment like nutrients concentration pattern over time and wave length and intensity of light pattern over time can be implemented and controlled and automated precisely using IOT controlled fluid/nutrient pumps and led of different wave lengths and all that can be real time monitored and controlled as well .

Now My questions related to agriculture :

Is there some standard numerical tabular or graphical data about concentration patterns or light wave length patterns and some rules that relate the quality and safety standard nutrition and chemical facts of the final fruit/vegetable to these patterns from plant biochemical point of view so that if theses patterns are implemented using such IOT system the quality and measured nutrition facts of the final fruit or vegetable can be tailored to meet specific requirement for the final crop of some type and variety of vegetable or fruit crop ?

Second Question what is the name of the field studying that and how to get such numerical data if exist ?

Thanks too much

Comment: Posting the same question on multiple sites is frowned upon on the SE network. Please choose the one you consider the best fit. Each site has an own [help], where the scope is explained. For Gardening SE, agriculture is explicitly off-topic, so I’m afraid your question will be closed here. As others on Earth Science have noted, Biology SE could be the best fit, but please check by yourself.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because agriculture is outside our scope and it’s a cross-post.